# Rank over rolling window in Python in a quick vectorised method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python. For every row in my data frame, I want to see its previous X number of rows using a rolling window and rank them in ascending order from 1..2..3 and then take that rank lists correlation with another list. However, I keep seeing the error cannot convert series to float. What should I do?

```
df[currency + '_'+type+'_ranked_correlation_'+time] = df[currency + '_'+type+'_cum_price_difference_1_before'].rolling(window=int(time), min_periods=int(time)).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=True)).corr(pd.Series(list(range(1, int(time) + 1))))
```

Here is an example I mention in the comments.Let's take a data frame where the X column is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -8 from top to bottom. If I take a rolling window of 2, for each row, I will look back at two rows including current row and rank the X column in ascending order (1, 2 or 2,1) and then take that rank's correlation against (1,2). Therefore, the final result is NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Could you post an example input and expected output?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Let's take a data frame where the X column is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -8 from top to bottom. If I take a rolling window of 2, for each row, I will look back at two rows including current row and rank the X column in ascending order (1, 2 or 2,1) and then take that rank's correlation against (1,2). Therefore, the final result is NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1. I hope that makes sense?